# Access Two Table SubReport - String Where

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a quick question about reports. I have a report that has two unbound subreports (the data is from two different databases and do not share any information. I usually opened these reports individually by using a simple UI to select different options and generate a string where and open the report ie,

```
DoCmd.OpenReport str_rptname, acViewReport, , strWhere
```

strWhere is made by the UI

Now that I have combined them into one report the string where does not work. Is it possible to pass a where string to a subform? If so how would I go about doing so? Is there another/better way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Why is this not working?

Comment: I believe it is because the string where opens the main report and sets the filter there, but the sub reports are not bound so open unfiltered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I can see you pinpointed the problem correctly as you wrote in your comment:

> I believe it is because the string where opens the main report and
>   sets the filter there, but the sub reports are not bound so open
>   unfiltered

Because the subreport are unbound you need to give them a complete recordset and not just a WHERE clause. Like this:

```
dim whereClause As String
dim strRecordset as String

'***Build your where clause

strRecordset = _
  "SELECT yourColumns " & _
  "FROM yourTables " & _
  "WHERE " & whereClause

Me.subreport.recordset = strRecordset
Me.subreport.Requery
```

Requery might be optional.